# 'Error inflating class fragment' error when following Maps API tutorial

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I've been following the [Xamarin Maps API tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/Guides/Android/Platform_Features/Maps_and_Location/Part_2_-_Maps_API/) and am consistantly running into problems. The most consistent of which is 'Android.Views.InflateException'. I have followed the toturial to the *absolute letter*, yet cannot find what the issue is. I have also reviewed the other similar questions on this problem, but nothing has helped - the project will not build at all.

[image]

MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace NewMapApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "NewMapApp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

                    // this line causes the error
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Stack trace:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:895
  at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:3830
  at NewMapApp.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x0000e] in /Users/rorymccrossan/Documents/Projects/Source/Testing/NewMapApp/NewMapApp/MainActivity.cs:26
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1943
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.10990ff1-ed31-42fe-a0e5-3d5d23292191 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
  at 
  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
  at    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
  at    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
  at    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
  at    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
  at    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
  at    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
  at    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
  at    at newmapapp.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
  at    at newmapapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
  at    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
  at    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
  at    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
  at    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
  at    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
  at    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
  at    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
  at    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
  at    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
  at    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  at Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
  at    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
  at    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:369)
  at    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
  at    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
  at    ... 22 more
  at
```

I am attempting to debug on a device (Samsung Galaxy S4) although it's not even getting that far when building.

As said above, I have followed all steps of the tutorial; added Google Play Services, all required permissions and now getting this. Can anyone guide me as to what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post the entirety of the stack trace? The screen shot of the exception does not contain enough information.

Comment: @BrettDuncavage sorry I forgot that. Added to the OP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue. The tutorial is missing an important setting in the AndroidManifest. As well as requiring certain permissions, you also need to provide the Google Play Services version as a meta-data node:

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

I have notified Xamarin of the problem by email, but will leave this question active in the hopes that it will help someone in the future.

Comment: This is a new piece of meta-data that showed up in rev 13 of Google Play Services. The maps & location docs were updated early just this morning to reflect the change. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TomOpgenorth no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not subclassing `FragmentActivity`, try:

```
// if you need to be compatible
using Android.Support.V4.App;
// if you don't need to be compatible
using Android.App;
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity // <- You MUST be a FragmentActivity if you want to use fragments in your activity.
```

And you should no longer have that runtime issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I don't need to support Froyo and lower.

Comment: The solution is still the same then. Just don't use the support version of the App namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the AndroidManifest.xml file with the following permissions worked for me:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```